# Transition/transform animation breaks on Safari iOS

Tags: ios, macos, safari, webkit, less

I have a radial progress indicator animation that breaks on Safari on iOS/OSX but works on every other Webkit browser I have tried it on.

You can see at this fiddle that there is a "tear" in the indicator.

http://jsfiddle.net/mLA7X/6826/

Comment: All OS-level bugs (and that includes Safari) should be reported to Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Okay, can this be confirmed as a bug then?

Comment: No-one on Stack Overflow can confirm this as a bug - only Apple. If you are confident in your code then report it as a bug with the example code.